# Keeping (python) paho MQTT connection alive indefinetly

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

Currently, I'm using the following function to publish to the MQTT broker:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

def publish_to_broker(data):
    publish.multiple(data, hostname=example_host, port=8883, client_id="example_id", keepalive=60,
                     will=None, auth={'username': "example_user", 'password': "example_password"},
                     tls={'ca_certs': certifi.where(), 'tls_version': ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2}, 
                     protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport="tcp")
```

Since this is establishing a new connection for every post, I need to change this to make it so that a connection remains active, and just reconnects if the connection is lost.

Sadly I found the docu quite unhelpful, for example the `tls=` part is only used with the method above, where the mqtt connection is closed right after the publishing. However, I would want to do this more like:

```
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(client_id="example_id", protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport="tcp")

mqtt_client.connect(host=example_host, port=8883, auth={'username': "example_user", 'password': "example_password"},  tls={'ca_certs': certifi.where(), 'tls_version': ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2})


def publish_to_broker_smart(data):
    mqtt_client.publish(data)
```

However, I get the error message: `TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'`

Where do these specifications fit in?

Answer (score 0):

tls and auth have to be specified differently. This is the way to go:

```
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(client_id=example_client, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport="tcp")
mqtt_client.username_pw_set(username, password)
mqtt_client.tls_set(ca_certs=certifi.where(), tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
mqtt_client.connect(host=example_host, port=8883)

def smart_post(data):
    mqtt_client.publish(topic=example_topic, payload=data, )
```